# Creating an array with identifier "name" in Javascript behaves as string, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was just creating an random array but i fell into an issue when i choose **"name"** as identifier.

I am writing this code:

```js
var name = ["test", 10, true];
console.log(name);
```

When i check console then instead of getting an array there it returns a string like `"test,10,true"`

If i change identifier from `"name"` to `"x"` or anything else then it works fine.

Can anyone please let me know what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning to `window.name`, which calls `toString()` on whatever you give it. You can't use `name` as a variable name at global scope.

Comment: And following the same idea, if you declare `name` as a `const`(block-scoped) instead of `var` (global scope) it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `name` is equivalent to the `window.name` property, and this is required to be a string. So your assignment is equivalent to

```
name = ["test", 10, true].toString();
```

You have to be careful with global variables, to make sure they don't conflict with `window` properties, since some of these have special behavior.